# Error trying update route53 with awscli and powershell

Tags: aws-cli

I am very new at awscli and programming in general.  I am tyring to update a route53 record when i start up an instance using cmd and powershell.   However, i keep getting this error when running it:

Error parsing parameter '--change-batch': Expected: '=', received: 'ÿ' for input:
ÿþ{

The commmand i am running is :
aws route53 change-resource-record-sets --hosted-zone-id Z337IOSIXTUZ2M --change-batch=file://C:\temp\config.json

I have tried just about all combinations like:
aws route53 change-resource-record-sets --hosted-zone-id Z337IOSIXTUZ2M --change-batch='C:\temp\config.json'

aws route53 change-resource-record-sets --hosted-zone-id Z337IOSIXTUZ2M --change-batch=file://C:\temp\config.json

aws route53 change-resource-record-sets --hosted-zone-id Z337IOSIXTUZ2M --change-batch=C:\temp\config.json

But nothing seems to work.  If i put the config.json file in my home directory on a ubuntu vm and run the same command it works, so i am pretty sure my problem is with the --change-batch stuff.

Any help would be very much appropriated as i have been working on this for a couple of days.

I keep getting this when try to run it:

Error parsing parameter '--change-batch': Expected: '=', received: 'ÿ' for input:
ÿþ{

Answer (score 0):

```
$ aws route53 change-resource-record-sets --hosted-zone-id Z337IOSIXTUZ2M --change-batch file://C:\temp\config.json
```

The parameters `change-batch` doesn't accept value with `=`. The above command should work for you.
Ref: [Route53 - Change Resource Record Set](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/route53/change-resource-record-sets.html)

Comment: Unfortunately when I run the above I am still getting :
PS C:\Users\bill> aws route53 change-resource-record-sets --hosted-zone-id Z337IOSIXTUZ2M --change-batch file://C:\temp\config.json

Error parsing parameter '--change-batch': Expected: '=', received: 'ÿ' for input:
ÿþ{
^

Comment: Then probably something wrong with your input JSON file.. maybe it's not correctly formatted.

Comment: Sorry if this is a dumb question, but does json have to be formatted differently for windows then in linux ?   The command is working on a Linux VM.

Comment: can you try adding backslashes before every double quote in your JSON file to check if that works for window machine?